# Preserve SVN revision number

Tags: svn, revision, preserve

I am a total newb to svn so this may be a very simple task to do.

I have my code with vendor that is using an svn for version control. I am also going to use svn in house but I was wondering if its possible to move the code onto my svn repository by preserving the version number. I have an inhouse issue log tracking tool that uses the version number to reference issues/tickets fixed.

If you can provide dumb down steps how to do this (if possible) it would be great.

Thanks 
s

Comment: It's not totally clear from your question what you want to do. You can of course *clone* an entire repository. If you do that, it will look like the original one until a commit on either one is made. You can not integrate this repo into an existing repo of yours. Think about it: Both repos will already have a revision 1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "merge" your repository and the vendor's in the way that you describe. What you're describing is what's called a [Vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) in Subversion parlance.  In short, you do the following:

- "Seed" the repository with what you currently have (vendor code + your customizations). Call this "trunk" for the sake of this explanation.
- Load each release of the vendor's code into a branch in your repository
- Merge the changes between the current release and the previous release into your trunk
- Handle any merge conflicts

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. What I am trying to do is have vendor dump the code from their svn version, I import the code into my svn version, however somehow keep the code revision number. I have seen somewhere svn dump command but I am not sure if that'd do it for me.

Comment: Why do you need a dump of their repository? They may not be willing (or able) to provide that - there may be information contained there which is not to be released outside their walls. In what way are their official releases insufficient for your needs, thereby necessitating that you get the full repository history? If you're going to that extent, they may as well give you direct access to their repository.

Comment: Its not their repository. Its mine, my code. At the moment its stored on their servers, I need to move it internally since they are not going to be my vendor any longer. Now since all my Re;ease notes / issue log tracking tools reference the version number which is tide into SVN version / revision number, once I move the code, I don't want the version / revsion starts from 1 once again but, from whatever is on their end. So, thats why its begs the question, once I move the code, how and if I can preserve that number ?

Comment: Then ask them to dump the repository in its entirety, end the data to you, and load it into a new repository on a server you control. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate